# How do I split "Hanako ate the sushi" at a grammatical level?

Tags: grammar, translation, english-to-japanese

Disclaimer: I'm not a Japanese learner, but I'm attempting a translation of a book, which has got a few examples in Japanese, among other languages, and I'd like to use Japanese characters, beside the transcriptions made using the English alphabet.

---

An English book I'm reading has an example in Japanese, but it renders it using the English alphabet, splitting apart some "words" to highlight what they mean in the sentence. To do so, it presents a table like this:

```
Hanako   ga         susi    o         tabeta
Hanako   SUBJECT    sushi   OBJECT    ate
```

the English meaning of the sentence being "Hanako ate the sushi".

My questions are:

- can I render those individual 5 parts of the sentence with 5 (or more) individual characters?
- And how do I put them together to get the whole sentence? As in, do I just put those characters side by side?

Comment: If you are asking whether the Japanese characters are connected with one another like Arabic, the answer is fortunately no, and they are placed from left to right (when written horizontally). So they fit well in that table. But I cannot be sure from the title that's what you are asking.

Comment: @aguijonazo I think they just want to know how to write the sentence in Japanese rather than romaji, but they don't know anything about Japanese, so they phrased it in a way that doesn't make any assumptions about how it should look, I guess.

Comment: Yes, I have no idea. Another phrasing would be "how do I shoehorn the sentence written in japanese into this table?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your questions, yes and yes. The sentence would be the following

> 花子が寿司を食べた

Individually, the words are

> 花子Hanako　がga　寿司sushi　をo　食べたtabeta

But when you write them out in a sentence regularly, just like the above, no space is needed and you write each word side by side.